# How to store value of result in an array for a calculation inside the loop

Tags: syntax, list-manipulation

**Note:** In my code I used `j` (ranging from 3 to 7) but I want `j` to be general

I tried this

```
i = 0;
For[j = 3, j < 10, j++,
 q[[i++]] = 2 + j]
q
```

Error: `Symbol q in part assignment does not have an immediate value`

I also tried initializing q

```
i = 0;
q = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
For[j = 3, j < 10, j++,
 q[[i++]] = 2 + j]
q
```

Output: `5[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0]`

I didn't understand why 5 is outside in `5[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0]`.In output, q doesn't look like Table.

Ok well!! while writing this I was checking suggestions and could solve it,
I tried

```
i = 0;
q = {};
For[j = 3, j < 10, j++,
 temp = 2 + j;
 AppendTo[q, temp];]
q
```

Is this a good way to do or are there even simple methods to code?

Comment: `q = Range[5, 11]`. See [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7924/alternatives-to-procedural-loops-and-iterating-over-lists-in-mathematica) for how to use loops in *Mathematica* (Hint: don't.). Also see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users) for how to avoid common pitfalls in MMA. Also: the weirdness in your second example is caused by using `i++`. Try `++i` instead.

Comment: Thanks for reminding the difference between post and pre increments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize ***i*** to be 1 rather than 0.

```
i = 1;
q = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

For[j = 3, j < 10, j++,
 q[[i++]] = 2 + j];

q
```

This yields

```
{5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}
```

In the step where you initialize q you could have used:

```
q = ConstantArray[0, 7];
```

However a much better approach is to use the comment from **march**. Use the `Range` function and you are done in one step.

```
q = Range[5,11]
```

Please do read the links that he provided you about loops.

Comment: +1. Now *why* is `i == 0` causing trouble? My favorite explanation: [86189](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86189/why-do-mathematica-list-indices-start-at-1)