# How can I implement arrays which begin with index 0

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to work with arrays (lists) whose first element has index `0` like arrays in C or Python. I cannot use `Part[]` since `expr[[0]]` is the head of `expr` and not its first element. I'm sure I'm not the only one to emulate C syntax in *Mathematica*. How can I do that?

Comment: Mathematica expressions are indexed from 1.  Index 0 gives you the head.  This is not something that can be changed.  For arrays, you can always have `myPart[arr_, i_] := Part[arr, i+1]`, with additional definitions for other syntaxes of `Part`.  But I still don't understand *the real motivation* behind wanting to do something like this. If you explain *why* you want this, maybe someone can come up with a better suggestion.

Comment: Just for the ease of programming… Take CoefficientsList[]. Wouldn't it be nice if the index of this list was the power of x of the polynomials ?

Comment: I also like the Fortran way where you declare an array as i_start:i_end. This way, the index of the array has a direct meaning in the problem you code.

Comment: If the only reason is that you like it better, I think that trying to do this is a very bad idea.  No matter what convention you use, 0-based or 1-based, there will be a problem for which it is not convenient. For that problem you'll just have to offset the indices.

Comment: Starting at 0 is also inconsistent with default iterators in _Mathematica_, for instance in `Table`, `Sum` etc. It's much less hassle to just adapt ;)

Comment: See [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/86189) as well.

Comment: A big problem with manually hacking `Part` is essentially every ``System`*`` function implemented top level uses `Part` and thus you will most likely break them.