# What's a[[-1]] of a table a?

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have a normal table $a$, what does $a[[-1]]$ mean, which element of the table?

Comment: The last one; see the docs of [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html).

Comment: [Here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/86195) is an answer of interest.

Answer (score 1):

a[[-1]] means the last element of table a. actually, the negative index means the order from the back,such as`{a,b,c,d}[[-2]]` is `c`, it helps to manipulate list more efficiently.